# Missing default model permissions during unit testing in Django app

Tags: django, django-unittest

There are default model permissions for view/add/update/delete in database when applying migrations(it's working with my main DB):

```
sadmonad=# select count(*) from auth_permission;
count 
-------
32
(1 row)
```

But in django.test it is not the case: it only creates permissions for django modules like auth, session, contenttype, etc:

```
test_sadmonad=# select count(*) from auth_permission;
count 
-------
24
(1 row)
```

I'm using Django 2.1.1(in my models I didn't specify custom permissions), so what should I do to fix this behaviour?